# How to debug a Simple GAN with LSTM Discriminator

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, generative-adversarial-network

Can you help me debugg my GAN?

I'm trying to build a GAN architecture similar to the one chosen in this Paper [Social-BiGAT: Multimodal Trajectory Forecasting
using Bicycle-GAN and Graph Attention Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.03395.pdf).
To achieve this, i started with the GAN implementation form this Tutorial [Build a Super Simple GAN in PyTorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-super-simple-gan-in-pytorch-54ba349920e4).
I have changed the setup form the tutorial in the following way.

An additional bit (0 or 1) in the dataset encodes if the generated even number should be < maxint/2 if 0 or >= maxint/2 if 1.
I have changed the generator and the discriminator to support the additional bit.
Additionally I have changed the discriminator to an LSTM architecture.

Unfortunately the generator is now unable to learn anything.
Can you help me either, to find the problem in my implementation, or give some tips how I can find it.

The Generator

```
class CondGenerator(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_length: int, num_classes: int = 1):
        super(CondGenerator, self).__init__()
        
        self.dense_layer1 = nn.Linear(int(input_length)+num_classes, int(input_length))
        self.dense_layer2 = nn.Linear(int(input_length), int(input_length))

        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor, labels: list = None) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = torch.cat([inputs, labels], dim=-1)
        x = self.activation(self.dense_layer1(x))
        x = self.activation(self.dense_layer2(x))
        return x
```

The discriminator:

```
class LSTMDiscriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,hidden_size: int, num_classes: int = 1):

        super(LSTMDiscriminator,self).__init__()
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.encoder_linear = nn.Linear(num_classes,hidden_size)
        self.merge_linear1 = nn.Linear(2*hidden_size,hidden_size)
        self.merge_linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,1)
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor, labels: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        
        features_encoded,_ = self.lstm(inputs)
        # get last ouput of lstm encoder
        features_encoded = features_encoded[:,-1,:]
        labels_encoded = self.encoder_linear(labels)
        encoding = torch.concat([features_encoded, labels_encoded], dim=-1)
        out = self.activation(self.merge_linear1(encoding))
        out = self.activation(self.merge_linear2(out))
        return out
```

The training loop

```
def lstm_train(max_int: int = 128,num_classes: int =1, batch_size: int = 16, training_steps: int = 500):

    input_length = int(math.log(max_int, 2))
    generator = CondGenerator(input_length,num_classes)
    discriminator = LSTMDiscriminator(8,1)

    # Optimizers
    generator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    discriminator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    # loss
    loss = nn.BCELoss()
    for i in tqdm(range(training_steps)):
        
        prnt = False
        if not i % 1000:
            prnt = True
            
        # zero the gradients on each iteration
        generator_optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Create noisy input for generator
        # Need float type instead of int
        noise = torch.randint(0, 2, size=(batch_size, input_length)).float()
        noise_labels = torch.randint(0,2,size=(batch_size,1)).float()
        generated_data = generator(noise, noise_labels)
        generated_data_seq = generated_data.reshape((batch_size, input_length,1))
        
        # Generate examples of even real data
        true_labels, true_data, true_data_labels = generate_even_conditional_data(max_int, batch_size=batch_size)
        
        true_labels = torch.tensor(true_labels).float()
        true_data = torch.tensor(true_data).float()
        true_data_labels = torch.tensor(true_data_labels).float()

        true_data_seq = true_data.reshape((batch_size, input_length,1))

        # Train the generator
        # We invert the labels here and don't train the discriminator because we want the generator
        # to make things the discriminator classifies as true.
        generator_discriminator_out = discriminator(generated_data_seq, noise_labels)
        generator_loss = loss(generator_discriminator_out, true_labels)
        generator_loss.backward()
        generator_optimizer.step()


        # Train the discriminator on the true/generated data
        discriminator_optimizer.zero_grad()
        true_discriminator_out = discriminator(true_data_seq, true_data_labels)
        true_discriminator_loss = loss(true_discriminator_out, true_labels)

        # add .detach() here think about this
        generator_discriminator_out = discriminator(generated_data_seq.detach(),noise_labels.detach())
        generator_discriminator_loss = loss(generator_discriminator_out, torch.zeros(batch_size,1))
        discriminator_loss = (true_discriminator_loss + generator_discriminator_loss) / 2
        discriminator_loss.backward()
        discriminator_optimizer.step()

        if prnt:
            res = convert_float_matrix_to_int_list(generated_data_seq)
            correct = 0
            for r,l in zip(res, noise_labels):
                if r%2 == 0 and ((l ==0 and r < max_int/2) or (l==1 and r >= max_int/2)):
                    correct += 1
            print(i," : ","generated_data: ", res, "correct rate: ", correct / len(res) )
            print(i, " : ", "noise_labels:   ", noise_labels.numpy().flatten())
            print(i," : ","discriminator_loss: ", discriminator_loss.item())
            print(i," : ", "generator_loss:     ", generator_loss.item())

max_int = 8
batch_size = 16
training_steps = 8000+1
num_classes = 1

lstm_train(max_int,num_classes, batch_size, training_steps)
```

A sample output

```
  0%|          | 36/8001 [00:00<00:42, 187.21it/s]
0  :  generated_data:  [6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6] correct rate:  0.375
0  :  noise_labels:    [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
0  :  discriminator_loss:  0.6919689178466797
0  :  generator_loss:      0.6256932020187378
 13%|█▎        | 1030/8001 [00:04<00:23, 294.89it/s]
1000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.4375
1000  :  noise_labels:    [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
1000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.16482460498809814
1000  :  generator_loss:      2.4430317878723145
 26%|██▌       | 2044/8001 [00:07<00:23, 258.99it/s]
2000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.5
2000  :  noise_labels:    [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
2000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.1819169521331787
2000  :  generator_loss:      2.7856388092041016
 38%|███▊      | 3045/8001 [00:11<00:17, 278.56it/s]
3000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.625
3000  :  noise_labels:    [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
3000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.2855352759361267
3000  :  generator_loss:      2.3989861011505127
 50%|█████     | 4033/8001 [00:14<00:15, 262.75it/s]
4000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.625
4000  :  noise_labels:    [0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
4000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.31603169441223145
4000  :  generator_loss:      3.0027859210968018
 63%|██████▎   | 5062/8001 [00:18<00:09, 307.91it/s]
5000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.625
5000  :  noise_labels:    [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
5000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.26022815704345703
5000  :  generator_loss:      2.6847457885742188
 75%|███████▌  | 6022/8001 [00:22<00:08, 241.49it/s]
6000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.4375
6000  :  noise_labels:    [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
6000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.12095952033996582
6000  :  generator_loss:      3.458857774734497
 88%|████████▊ | 7061/8001 [00:26<00:03, 294.43it/s]
7000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.375
7000  :  noise_labels:    [1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
7000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.23924894630908966
7000  :  generator_loss:      3.617945909500122
100%|██████████| 8001/8001 [00:30<00:00, 265.88it/s]
8000  :  generated_data:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] correct rate:  0.5
8000  :  noise_labels:    [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
8000  :  discriminator_loss:  0.20328140258789062
8000  :  generator_loss:      3.33994197845459
```

Comment: It looks like the discriminator loss is decreasing and the generator loss is increasing. Try freezing the trained discriminator and only training the generator. If the generator learns, that means it just needs more training steps relative to the discriminator. If not, it indicates problems elsewhere.